# Subset of unique names

Tags: r, subset

I have a vector of IDs length 18

```
mydata$ID=rep(c("WT1","WT2", "WT3", "KO1", "KO2", "KO3"), each=3)

[1] "WT1" "WT1" "WT1" "WT2" "WT2" "WT2" "WT3" "WT3" "WT3" "KO1" "KO1" "KO1" "KO2" "KO2" "KO2" "KO3"
[17] "KO3" "KO3"
```

I want to create a  new vector with the same order of elements but taken singularly, like this:

```
WT1 WT2 WT3 KO1 KO2 KO3
```

I have tried:

```
mydata$ID=factor(unique(mydata$ID))
```

But it returns:

```
[1] WT1 WT2 WT3 KO1 KO2 KO3 WT1 WT2 WT3 KO1 KO2 KO3 WT1 WT2 WT3 KO1 KO2 KO3
```

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do with the new vector

Comment: Note that the problem in the question occurs upon assignment back to the data frame, where the result is recycled to fill.

Comment: `mydata$ID` has a length of 18. It is a subset of a data frame/data table, when you assign a vector of length 6 to it, you are asking it to either recycle the vector 3x or return an incompatible df, which it will not do. Are you trying to alter an existing object or create a new one?

Comment: The new vector will serve as raw names for an heatmap. The data for the heatmap will be the average of the triplicates. So the new dataframe (for the heatmap) will have  6 raws.

Comment: A length of 6 or six rows?  They are different.  A length 6 data frame has six columns.  Please show the desired result in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's keep this simple:

```
unique(mydata$ID)
[1] "WT1" "WT2" "WT3" "KO1" "KO2" "KO3"
```

Answer (score -1):

Install the sqldf package.  Then do

```
newVector <- sqldf('select distinct(ID) from mydata');
```